# Does Google's mobile vision support languages other than the English?

Tags: android, google-vision

I've used Google's vision API to extract text (only English) from any given images in one of my android application. The application fetches every libraries needed, online, only once at the time of installation and then can extract the English text out of an image without the need of the internet after that. Is it possible to achieve the same result with languages other than English?
Lately, I came to know about the Google's Cloud Vision API which does support different languages but it requires the internet every time you want to scan images. So, to be precise, I just want to know if I can extract texts of any other languages from an image just adding this line in the app dependencies and if yes, then how?

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the official documentation of Google Mobile Vision APIs, it can work with these languages just like ti works with English.

> The Text API can recognize text in any Latin based language. This
>   includes, but is not limited to:
>
> Catalan Danish Dutch English Finnish French German Hungarian Italian
>   Latin Norwegian Polish Portugese Romanian Spanish Swedish Tagalog
>   Turkish

Comment: What about Hindi, Chinese, or any other languages that has different scripts than that of English?

Comment: They won't work currently. These are the only languages supported by the APIs currently. Please consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem.